# How do I get in the ball park of a cartographer map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently saved up and purchased a cartographer map:

[image]

I'm the little tiny blip in the upper right, meaning that I'm pretty far away from it. How do I know which direction to go to get closer to the general vicinity of the woodland mansion?

Comment: I would head south until your blip is somewhere along the right side of the map, then head west.  I'm not sure what that would be in X Y Z terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that dot is in the upper right corner of the map, you have to go south-west to find the mansion.

But how do you find out where south-west is?

You can either observe various environmental clues, the main one being the sun which rises in the east and sets in the west. The easier way would be to hit <kbd>F3</kbd> and see the orientation you're currently facing.

[image]